# PDO set value in prepare

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindparam

I get error on this code.. I set UserName and Password but i get error. What is the my fail ?

```
$Id=$db->prepare("select UserID from Users where 1=1 and IsActive=1 and Name=:UserName and Password=:Password");
$Id->bindParam(":UserName",$UserName,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Id->bindParam(":Password",$Password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Id->execute();
```

This is error:

> PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:
>   number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: Are you sure `$UserName` and `$Password` are both set? If they are, I do not see any reason why it would cause that error. The [first example](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#refsect1-pdostatement.bindparam-examples) in the documentation should be the same thing you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I've never had any reason to use `bindParam` or `bindValue` because you can simply pass an associative array into [execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) function as shown below:

```
$Id = $db->prepare("select UserID from Users where 1=1 and IsActive=1 and Name=:UserName and Password=:Password");
$Id->execute(array(":UserName" => $UserName, ":Password" => $Password));
```

Comment: While interesting, this doesn't actually explain why the OP's code failed.